# How to remove query string of static resources using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I currently have a file url of `www.abc.com/images/mainbanner01.jpg`, but got a query string of `www.abc.com/images/mainbanner01.jpg?1372831425923`

My file currently being read as `www.abc.com/images/mainbanner01.jpg?1372831425923`, based on the Google Speed test, they want me to removed the query string from this static resources.

So, how can I remove the query string using **htaccess** so that my file will be read as `www.abc.com/images/mainbanner01.jpg` only?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to access the image `www.abc.com/images/mainbanner01.jpg` but it requires a query string which should not be displayed ?

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: My file currently being read as www.abc.com/images/mainbanner01.jpg?1372831425923, based on the Google Speed test, they want me to removed the query string from this static resources.

So, how can I remove the query string using htaccess so that my file will be read as www.abc.com/images/mainbanner01.jpg only?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the caching values for static content into .htaccess file via mod_expires. Should help out.